# How old is Kal-EL/Superman?

Tags: dc, superman, arrowverse, the-flash-2014, age

I was watching the Flash TV series, and I was wondering how old Superman/Kal El is supposed to be in that series.

Comment: This question is far too broad to be answered generally, but since you've asked about the Flash TV series specifically, I've added a tag to narrow it down.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the pilot and first season opener of *Supergirl* (2015), which introduced the Tyler Hoechlin Superman, Kara states:

> "24 years ago, my planet Krypton was in serious peril. My cousin,
> Kal-El, was sent to a planet called Earth for his own safety and
> protection. You may know his story."

Kal-El was born in 1979 (Earth time) and arrived on Earth relatively instantaneously.  Compared to Kara, born in 1966 (Earth time) and arriving on Earth in 2003, appearing like a 13 year-old.

Accordingly Superman is presently 42 or so.

However, age for the *Supergirl* cast is [notoriously misaligned](https://io9.gizmodo.com/cws-supergirl-casts-lex-luthor-and-now-no-ones-age-make-1830500535); oft highlighted is how Lilian Luthor, played by Brenda Strong is 61, is the mother of Lex Luthor, played by Jon Cryer who is 56.

Comment: Actor age is very often wholly unrelated to character age. Men in Hollywood tend to be a "child" into their mid-20s, "young" into their 30s, and "middle-age" into their 50s (or later, with hair coloring), while women tend to be a "child" in their mid-teens, "young" until their mid 20s and "middle-age" through their 30s. Women actors have a notoriously difficult time finding work in their 40s and 50s at all (except for voice acting) as they're "too old" to be middle age and "too young" to be elderly.